# how to add an environment variable to root user?

Tags: variables, unix, environment-variables, root, sudo

I'm trying to set an environment variable to root user: `TMPDIR=/var/hello/tmp`

I need it to show up when I do

```
sudo printenv
```

I'm not connected as root, and I don't know the root password.

What I've tried:

```
export TMPDIR=/var/hello/tmp
```

problem: this sets the env for me, but not for root user

```
sudo env TMPDIR=/var/hello/tmp
```

problem: it prints out a list of env variables with TMPDIR set, but when I `sudo printenv` afterwards, I don't see it

```
sudo -i
export TMPDIR=/var/hello/tmp
printenv
```

problem: I see it, but when I do `sudo printenv` I don't see it. Am I not in the root user when I do sudo -i?

```
TMPDIR=/var/hello/tmp
sudo -e TMPDIR
```

problem: this opens up a file in vi, which I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do. When I quit, nothing happens

```
emacs /etc/profile
#put export TMPDIR=/var/hello/tmp in the file
```

problem: I don't see it in `sudo printenv` when I restart the shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
sudo TMPDIR=/var/foo/tmp VAR2=value2 myprog arg1 arg2 ...
```

Alternatively, create a shell script setting all environment variables and executing the program and run it instead.